# Getting "You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)" when trying to use Kubernetes on Docker desktop

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I've enabled Kubernetes on Docker Desktop (on a Mac) - and when I run

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yml
```

I get -

```
"error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)"
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was that somehow context was changed.
Checked it by

```
kubectl config current-context
```

and then changed it back to the correct one by

```
kubectl config use-context docker-desktop
```